# How can I loop through a set of strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple for loop that I need to set up. However instead of iterating through numbers I would like to iterate through:

```
"A", "B", "1" and then "2"
```

Is there a way I can do this with just creating an inline array?

Comment: you have to be more specific about the order, if it's just four things - what's the problem with creating an array? You have to specify what you're iterating through _somewhere_ and unless there is a pattern, I don't see how you can avoid writing it down.

Comment: so where do you store your values then?

Comment: Why is an array a problem? It could be as simple as `["A", "B", "1", "2"].forEach(...)`

Comment: You could do `Array.prototype.forEach.call('AB12', ...)`, but why?

Comment: @Yoshi your solution would be fine but how would I access those values inside of the loop?

Comment: Well, just have a look at the [manual...](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you would like to replace the usage of `for()` loop

```
var i;
var array = ["A", "B", "1", "2"];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    alert(array[i]);
}
```

You can do that by simply using `forEach()` function

```
var array = ["A", "B", "1", "2"];
array.forEach(function(value) {
    alert(value);
});
```